# IIS 7.5: Internal Server Error for virtual directories and apps running under sites

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to set up an ASP.NET MVC 4 application to run under an already configured website based on ASP.NET MVC 4. I.e. I want to have an application run under http://dev.site.local/myApp but no matter how I do it, if I configure it either as an app or as a virtual directory I always get Internal Server Error upon trying to access it.

Output from IIS log:

```
2012-12-03 10:05:14 127.0.0.1 GET /Ekstranett - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/22.0.1229.94+Safari/537.4 500 19 183 0
```

Is anyone able to assist in debugging and solving this most frustrating problem?

EDIT: After some thorough googling I've managed to interpret the log entry as Invalid configuration data. Still hard at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be the lack of proper permissions. I set the right permissions and then it all worked out.